# Chamar função jQuery ao renderizar componente via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, placeholder

Estou com um pequeno problema que é o seguinte:

Eu possuo um componente `RichFaces` mais especificamente o `rich:listShuttle` com id `"migrarId"`. Dentro desse componente eu tenho um `input` que possui um `placeholder` que é gerado via *jQuery* sempre que a página é carregada.

O problema é que esse `input` possui possui um *ajax* com o evento `"onkeyup"` que quando digito e apago alguma coisa ele **reRenderiza** todo o componente do `rich` o que acaba fazendo o `placeholder` sumir.

```
`<h:inputText styleClass="filtroOrigem" id="filtroOrigem" value="#{migrarUsuarioManagedBean.filtroOrigem}">
 <a4j:support requestDelay="1000" event="onkeyup" ajaxSingle="true" process="filtroDestino" action="#{migrarUsuarioManagedBean.filtrarDestino}" reRender="migrarId" />
</h:inputText>`

    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('input.filtroOrigem').attr("placeholder", "Digite Chave, Nome ou Unidade");
    });
```

Eu queria saber se existe alguma forme de gerar o `placeholder` sempre que esse componente é renderizado via *ajax* e não quando a página é carregada.

Comment: Se tiver algum `value` no input o placeholder não aparece! Quando vc reRenderiza o campo vc está deixando algum value no input? Se estiver o placeholder não vai aparecer...

Comment: O que me deixou intrigada é pq fazer isso com jQuery, ao invés de colocar o placeholder diretamente no input.